# How to remove an element index wise from an array of rectangles where the height of any rectangle is zero?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'am trying to remove an element from an array of rectangles where the height of an element is 0.
I have an array of 10 rectangles, 2 of which has height 0. I can do this easily in List<>, but the code is using this array in a lot of places and I dont want to change that.

I know how to remove an element from a regular integer of string array as below, but how to remove it from an array of rectangles?

```
      int[] array = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2 };
    int item = 4;

    List<int> nums = new List<int>(array);
    nums.RemoveAt(nums.IndexOf(item));
    array = nums.ToArray();
```

Comment: @PeterCsala Hi, I had read that answer, its again for integers and strings. I cant find how to define the height to remove it from array

Comment: @Alisha please share the actual code then. Also principle will still be the same.

Comment: @PeterCsala There is no code, I cant figure out how to delete an element from it

Comment: "I can do this easily with List" - but the code you show also uses List, so what's the problem then?

Comment: @Evk The code is for integer, I cant figure out how to do it with an array of rectangles

Comment: Replace the word int in List<int> with the word Rectangle or whatever the classname is you have instead.

Comment: `rectangles = rectangles.Where(rectangle => rectangle.Height > 0).ToArray();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code could do it. It's going through the array backward, to avoid indices to change when items are removed.

```
List<Rectangle> rects = new List<Rectangle>(array);
for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if (array[i].Height == 0)
   {
       rects.RemoveAt(i);
   }            
}
array = rects.ToArray();
```

Or, if you don't mind a bit of linq

```
array = array.Where(x => x.Height != 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Psst...change ` > 0` to ` >= 0` or you'll miss checking that first element in the list!  ;)

Comment: you don't need `var test`, you can just do `array = array.Where(...).ToArray();`

Comment: @Idle_Mind Oops, good point. fixed.